# Passing Parse.com Xamarin SDK "ParseObject" in bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, parse-platform, xamarin

I'm using the Parse.com Xamarin/.NET in a Xamarin Android app. I need to pass an object to a fragment from my master activity. However, since ParseObject extends from `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` and `KeyValuePair` is not serializable I'm struggling to figure out how to pass my objects around in an argument bundle or an intent bundle.

I've created a solution where I only pass the objectId in an intent and then perform a get against the SDK to retrieve the object. But this is creating unnecessary network traffic.

The only solution I've found on stackoverflow or the parse help pages so far suggest that I should hold my object in a static variable in either the activity or application class. But, multiple instances of my fragment can exist at the same time so my static objects would collide in this scenario -- not to mention that would put a dependency on an instance outside of the fragment.

I'm mostly looking for what other people have done in this type of scenario. The best solution that I can think of that reduces network traffic is with an interface -- essentially creating a "GetObject" method on the activity that the fragment could execute. But that seems a little sloppy, and it doesn't work so well when its activity to activity or activity to service.

Comment: I haven't used Parse, but can't you just keep/get a reference to the fragment and call a setter on it? Something like:

Activity creates Fragment
Activity gets/keeps reference to Fragment.
Fragment has setter-method.
Activity calls setter-method.

Comment: that seems like a viable options. I think rather though, using the standard fragment practices, I'll enforce a property on an interface within the fragment and the calling activity needs to implement the property.

I still have to figure out how to work with the objects between activities and services though.